# How do you delete documents for good on Google Docs?

Tags: google-docs

I have documents on Google Docs that I either don't want or need. However, when I delete them, leave the site, and then return, they're still there, like I haven't deleted them at all. If you know the answer to this problem, please send me it. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

When you delete documents from Google Docs (or Google Sheets, for that matter), they end up in the Trash. You can empty your trash via [Google Drive](https://drive.google.com/drive/u/0/trash):

[image]

Comment: Thanks man very helpful

Comment: You're welcome. If this solved your problem, you can 'Accept' the answer: https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: actually it didn't work man, I just checked and they're still there]

Comment: Bummer ... then I have no idea how to solve it. I hope somebody else comes along ...

Comment: I'll get back to you if i find the answer

Comment: Please do, and post it as an answer; it's [encouraged](/help/self-answer) to answer your own question here.